# Find the names and telephone numbers of all customers who borrowed a particular CD

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to be able to find the names and telephone numbers of all customers who borrowed a particular CD and had to return it by a particular date.

I have tables set up for CD (title, type, year) and rents (rent data, duration).

My attempt is below:

```
$query = "SELECT name, tel FROM customer WHERE '$_POST[cd_title]'  AND '$_POST[rent_date]'; ";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['tel'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
echo "</table>";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
echo "1 record found and listed";
```

However, nothing shows up and I'm not getting any errors besides the die statement( Error: ). I can't tell what's wrong at this point. I'm assuming it's my query but what makes it wrong?

Comment: NEVER include `$_POST` variables directly in your query. Escape them first if you really need to use `mysql_*` functions.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the column names in the `WHERE` clause

try this

```
$query = "SELECT name, tel FROM customer WHERE columnNameForTitle = '$_POST[cd_title]'  AND columnNameForRentDate = '$_POST[rent_date]'; ";
```

[Here's](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) the syntax for a SQL query with a WHERE clause

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a condition in your query; you need to add a condition on the `WHERE` predicate.

As you are using `mysqli`, you can use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). The below is adapted from the documentation:

```
$q = "SELECT name, tel FROM customer WHERE title = ? AND rent_date = ?";

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$stmt =  $mysqli->stmt_init(); # Initialize a statement
$stmt->prepare($q); # prepare it with the query
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['title'],$_POST['rent_date']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($name, $tel); # Set the return values

# Fetch results
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $tel . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

$stmt->close(); # close the statement
```

The key line is [`bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), which takes your input and binds it to a prepared statement; it also takes care of properly escaping your input.

Each `?` in your statement is a placeholder (called a parameter). Its where you will place a variable (this is called *binding*). So you have to tell `bind_param` what types of variables are going for each `?`, so it can convert/escape the values properly.

The types are:

```
Character   Description
i           corresponding variable has type integer
d           corresponding variable has type double
s           corresponding variable has type string
b           corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
```

Since there are two `?`s in your query, and they both are strings, that's why you see two `s`'s in the call. Then after the comma, you type the variable that holds the value you want to send to the database.  The number of types must match the number of `?` and of course you need to pass in an equal number of values as well.

Comment: You're right, that's a mistake. definitely not adding records. Just listing them. Also, see the post again... I'm using mysqli. Would your result be the same in mysqli?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should contain column names to fetch the records. something like:

```
"SELECT name, tel FROM customer WHERE field1 = 'value' AND field2 = 'value2'";
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of readable code

```
// Change cd_title and rent_date with your columns names
$query = "SELECT name, tel FROM customer WHERE cd_title = '{$_POST["cd_title"]}' AND rent_date = '{$_POST["rent_date"]}';";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    // HEREDOC for html readability, see http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc
    echo <<<HTML
    <tr>
        <td>{$row["name"]}</td>
        <td>{$row["tel"]}</td>
    </tr>
HTML;

}

echo "</table>";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

echo "1 record added";
```

I hope it works.

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS CODE. Do not embed `$_POST` variables directly in your query. ALWAYS, always, always escape your strings if you really have to use `mysql_*` functions. (I am aware you've copied this form the question but don't repeat his mistake)

Comment: I'm just answering the question, i'll not make his homework :)